# При попытке обрезать число слов/символов в слаге не проверяет на уникальность

Tags: wordpress

Столкнулся с тем, что после добавления кода для уменьшения количества слов в слаге не срабатывает проверка на уникальность слага. И в итоге появилась возможность плодить записи с одинаковыми слагами.

Можете порекомендовать как решить эту проблему?

Код даю ниже:

```
function pm_trim_native_slug($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent) {
    global $wpdb;

    $max_words = 5; // Limit the number of words to 5; This value can be changed.
    $words = explode('-', $slug);

    if(count($words) > $max_words) {
        $slug = implode("-", array_slice($words, 0, $max_words));

        // Make the slugs unique
        $check_sql       = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $slug, $post_ID));

        if($post_name_check) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = _truncate_post_slug($slug, 200 - (strlen($suffix) + 1)) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent));
                $suffix++;
            } while ($post_name_check);
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    }

    return $slug;
}
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug', 'pm_trim_native_slug', 99, 5);
```

Comment: Проверил - ваш код работает, как я и предполагал. Покажите ситуацию, при которой он не работает.

Comment: Ситуация проявляется когда я сохраняю черновики с именами "Тестовая очень длинная запись номер один" и, например, "Тестовая очень длинная запись номер два". Он всем черновикам давал слаг "ochen-dlinnaya-zapis-nomer". После вашего комментария попробовал опубликовать эти записи и там, действительно уникальность сработала и слаги поменялись. Спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: Вот что значит - правильно прокомментировать )))